# Trying to install gcc on a linux terminal, but I get an error

Tags: linux, terminal, gcc

Trying to install gcc on my computer, but I get this error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf0_2.34-6ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.34-6ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.34-6ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-81.91_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I type "gcc" again, it just tells me to sudo apt install it again. Any advice?

Comment: You are being told to run `apt-get update`, have you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gcc
```